# How to use AFNetworking with multi-request?

Tags: afnetworking, multitasking

I have some requests in the same time, I want to deal with it until they are all done.
Here are requests:

```
[self getProfileData];
[self checkNewSystemMessage];
[self checkChatMessage];
```

In the  `getProfileData`  it looks like:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager* manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
NSString * portNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"portNumber"];

[manager GET:URL_ADDRESS(portNumber,@"JsonEntryManager") parameters:dic success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
    //Do something...
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(getProfileData) withObject:nil afterDelay:REQUEST_AGAIN_TIME];
}];
```

and others are the same.
I want do something when they are all done. The only way I thought is that request them one by one. Obviously it's a foolish idea. So how can I know the end time?

Answer (score 0):

Before you start any request initialize counter:

```
int counter = 0;
```

and in success block of each request, do

```
counter++;
if(counter==3)
{
    //Do what you need to do when all the request is completed.
    //Make some method for this.
}
```

Comment: It works almostly, but if two methods end in the same time and they want to change counter both, it's a problem.

Comment: True that! I haven't thought about it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure out that too, but right now what is successfully working for me is to check the number of operations inside of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`'s OperationQueue inside of **success** **block**:

```
[manager GET:URL_ADDRESS(portNumber,@"JsonEntryManager") parameters:dic success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

if ([weakSelf.manager.operationQueue operationCount] == 0) {
       //Do something here when all the operations are done.
    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(getProfileData) withObject:nil afterDelay:REQUEST_AGAIN_TIME];
}];
```